# Change the color of a path based on the number of transports that have passed

Tags: anylogic

I'm quite new at Anylogic and I would like to know if there is a way to change the color of a path based the number of transport passed on it.
For example: if 10 transporter have passed on path1 then i want to change the color from blue to green.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1. Have a map where you store the path as a key and a counter as the value

[image]

2. Then on the fleet settings you simple increment the counter of the map every time a transporter enters it.

In the fleet object under the "On enter path" section add the following code

`pathEntryCounter.merge(path, 1, Integer::sum);`

3. Then in the path color have the color set dynamically based on the number of the counter in the map

[image]